# usar un trigger entre dos servidores diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, insert, connection

tengo la logica de mi trigger creada en SQL SERVER, pero necesito que cuando se crea un registro en una tabla, se escriba otro en otra base de datos que esta alojada en OTRO SERVIDOR. como hago para que el trigger conecte los dos servidores y ejecute la instruccion?

EDIT: este es el escenario: una base de datos contiene la lista de trabajadores, y el codigo de tarjeta que se le da a cada uno de ellos cuando ingresa a la compañia. en otro servidor, esta la BD que gestiona el sistema de accesos, puertas y barreras de acceso al parqueo. se desea que al registrar un nuevo empleado o que se modifique la tarjeta, automaticamente se cree o actualice el registro en la BD del sistema de puertas. las dos BD no son iguales ni niguna de sus tablas, pero comparten muchos datos en comun.

ya se sabe la estructura de las tablas y se tiene una plantilla para una carga masiva, pero se requiere un proceso de automatización para que se agregue o se actualice el registro sin intervencion del usuario

Este es mi codigo, cuando las dos bases de datos estan en el mismo server. ya esta probado y funciona, pero la base AXTRAX1 esta en otro servidor

```
use datacard
go

CREATE TRIGGER crearTarjeta ON IDWabogado_nuevo FOR INSERT AS
    BEGIN
        declare @carnet as integer
        declare @nombre as varchar(50)
        declare @ap1 as varchar(50)
        declare @ap2 as varchar(50)
        declare @fechaemi as datetime
        declare @fechavenc as datetime
        declare @cedula as VARCHAR(10)
        declare @maxid as integer
        declare @numtarjeta as integer

        select @carnet=IDWcarne,@cedula=IDWcedula,@numtarjeta=IDWnumtarjeta,@nombre=IDWnombre,@ap1=IDWapellido1,@ap2=IDWapellido2,@fechaemi=IDWfechaexp,@fechavenc=IDWFechaVencimiento from inserted;
        INSERT INTO [AxTrax1].[dbo].[tblEmployees] VALUES (@carnet,@ap2,@nombre,'10000','',@fechaemi,'','','',38,@fechaemi,@fechavenc,1,'','','','','',0,0,@ap1,'',0,0,'0x',1,0,1,1,0,@carnet,0,0,0,0,'',0,0,@fechaemi,'','','','','',255,0,0,0,'',0,0,@cedula,'',0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0);

select @maxid=max([IdCardNum]) from [AxTrax1].[dbo].[tblCard]
        INSERT INTO [AxTrax1].[dbo].[tblCard] VAlues(@maxid+1,183,CONCAT('183',' ,','00000000000',@numtarjeta),'2000-01-01 00:00:00.000',1,1,@carnet,@numtarjeta,'2000-01-01 00:00:00.000','-1','-1',1)

    END
```

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es establecer replicación transaccional.

Comment: hola @LuisCazares no, ya que las dos bases de datos son diferentes entre si. explico mejor mi caso: una base de datos contiene la lista de trabajadores, y el codigo de tarjeta que se le da a cada uno de ellos cuando ingresa a la compañia. en otro servidor, esta la BD que gestiona el sistema de accesos, puertas y barreras de acceso al parqueo. se desea que al registrar un nuevo empleado o que se modifique la tarjeta, automaticamente se cree o actualice el registro en la BD del sistema de puertas. las dos BD no son iguales ni niguna de sus tablas, pero comparten muchos datos en comun

Comment: podes especificar que se replique una sola tabla, el trigger en origen agrega a esa tabla otro trigger en destino lee de esa tabla

Comment: También podrías crear un linked server para hacer referencia al otro servidor desde el trigger, pero eso puede hacer que las modificaciones a la tabla sean muy lentas.

Comment: Linked server, un sinónimo de eso en la base local y con eso puedes usar la tabla remota sin lío

Comment: también podes hacer q el frontend que crea el primer registro lo haga en el segundo servidor

Comment: Como indicaron antes, linked server es una buena opción. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lo logre con un linked server entre los dos hosts, y un trigger

Comment: Con una explicación iría bien la respuesta...

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).